# Packet injection, filtering and mangling WITHOUT GPL?

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

I'll have to do packet inspection, mangling, dropping and injection of packets on a Linux system. Ideally, this would be in user space and on IP packets and Ethernet frames, too.

Unfortunately, I cannot go OpenSource for this which basically rules out any approach based on `NFQUEUE` and `libnetfilter_queue`, since all of `netfilter` (and their dog) is GPL only.

I thought about using TAP/TUN devices in parallel to controlling `netfilter` by simply calling `iptables`, but this seems to be messy at best...

So, are there any alternatives to `netfilter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that `libnetfilter` is subject to the GPLv2 licence (not LGPL) and any project building on these would thus be subject to the GPLv2 licence too; this is what you want to avoid (I think).

An alternative would be to use a language binding which is not subject to the GPLv2 licence. One candidate would appear to be the Go bindings - see [here](https://github.com/smarterclayton/geard/tree/master/pkg/go-netfilter-queue) for example, which appears to be under the Apache licence. I have obviously not checked the provenance of every file therein. Another way would be to divide your application into two - a small layer that communicates with Netfilter, communicating via (e.g.) an RPC interface with the rest of your application.

However, the last time I faced this, I used `libpcap` instead, which is BSD licensed. It's a little known fact that `libpcap` can send raw packets as well as receive them. However, it is much lower level than netfilter - you get raw packets and that's about it.

Answer (score -1):

The license does not apply to your userspace application.

Comment: That is untrue. The licensing is set out explicitly at http://www.netfilter.org/licensing.html - libnetfilter is GPLv2, meaning anything that links to it is a derived work, and is thus subject to the terms of the GPLv2.